# Множественное добавление данных

Tags: php, yii

Есть таблица связей, состоящая из 2 колонок (id каталога, id модели).

Есть массив чисел (id моделей) и id каталога.

**Как лучше добавить массив в базу?**

*Мысли:*

1. В цикле создавать модели и сохранять модели (но, на мой взгляд, слишком много запросов может получиться).
2. Создать один свой sql-запрос для добавления (самому необходимо формировать sql, кажется не безопасно).

**Есть еще варианты добавления?**

---

**добавлено:**

Массив может быть до 5000.

Comment: На сколько большой массив?

Comment: @Barton до 5000.

Comment: А что мешает сделать через SQL?

Comment: @IVsevolod рекомендую генерить sql, склеивать запросы в одну строку, например по 20 insert, и дальше в цикле их выполнять. Это вполне нормальный способ для такого количества данных.

Comment: Через 1 запрос, на php  валидаторов пруд пруди.

Comment: @VasyOk вообще ничего. Просто в проекте старались уходить от прямых sql запросов. Думал, что есть какие-то стандартные средства под Yii

Comment: У нас на быстро склеенном парсере на yii2 добавляются модели по одной, 350 метров хмл / 200 000 записей (+ связи с категориями) разбираются за пять часов на самом слабом DO-дроплете (причем 90% загрузки проца уходит на мускуль). В общем, не фонтан, но жить можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут нужно для начала решить такой вопрос: если сейчас или в будущем могут появиться поведения модели при добавлении новой строки в базу, то тут одним запросом вы не сможете обойтись, так как при таком подходе события не будут отрабатывать.

Если же таких ситуаций не будет в обозримом будущем, то делайте валидацию и создавайте запросы на множественную вставку. Но тут еще есть ограничения на размер запроса у MySQL.

Я в свое время при написании загрузки прайс-листов вышел экспериментальным путем на 500 строк за 1 запрос, при том что база была не локальная, а соединение по инету.

Да, кстати, в YII2 точно помню, что множественная вставка реализована в коробке, по поводу YII 1.0 не подскажу.

Comment: К сожалению, Yii 1.0.

Я обычно делал по 100 записей. ) Спасибо за мысли и советы. )

Comment: Переходите на YII2. )) Да и, кстати, php >5.5 имеет хорошие изменения для работы с большими массивами данных generators - см. тут: http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/chto-nas-zhdjot-v-php-5.5